# wxFileDialog ShowModal issue

Tags: c++, user-interface, wxwidgets

I'm new to wxWidgets and I'm trying to use the wxFileDialog, but after using it for some time I have noticed an issue with using it.

after calling the:

> ShowModal() //For: wxFileDialog

my program grows ~8000K and after every next call it grows ~1000K.

below is the code I'm using to test the issue, I assume I'm doing something very wrong and have no idea what I've looked all over for a fix and can't seem to find anything.

I assume there's memory being allocated somewhere but never deallocated...

Anyone who could help with the issue, it would be greatly appreciated!

```
#include <wx\wxprec.h>

class MyApp : public wxApp {
public:
    virtual bool OnInit();
};

class My_Frame : public wxFrame {
public:
    My_Frame() : wxFrame(NULL, wxID_ANY, _T("Test"), wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, wxDEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE & ~wxRESIZE_BORDER & ~wxMAXIMIZE_BOX) {
        wxButton* newButton = new wxButton(this, LOAD_FILE_BROWSER_ID, "PRESS ME");
    }

    void on_button_press(wxCommandEvent& event);

    enum ButtonID {
        LOAD_FILE_BROWSER_ID = wxID_HIGHEST + 1
    };

    DECLARE_EVENT_TABLE()
};

IMPLEMENT_APP(MyApp)

bool MyApp::OnInit() {
    My_Frame* newFrame = new My_Frame;
    newFrame->Show(true);
    return true;
}

BEGIN_EVENT_TABLE(My_Frame, wxFrame)

EVT_BUTTON(My_Frame::ButtonID::LOAD_FILE_BROWSER_ID, My_Frame::on_button_press)

END_EVENT_TABLE()

void My_Frame::on_button_press(wxCommandEvent& WXUNUSED(event)){
    wxFileDialog FileLoad(this, "Load", "", "", "", wxFD_OPEN | wxFD_FILE_MUST_EXIST);
    FileLoad.ShowModal();
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    wxEntryStart(argc, argv);
    wxTheApp->CallOnInit();
    wxTheApp->OnRun();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Opening a file dialog loads a number of DLLs under Windows (where you must be testing this), many of them third party ones (shell extensions and such) and which may have memory leaks. Unfortunately if this is really the case there is nothing you can do about it, except finding the DLL leaking memory and stopping using it. To be really sure that it's not a wxWidgets problem you could write, or find online, a simple Win32 application using the open file dialog directly and check if it exhibits the same symptoms -- it really should.